# How can I combine sprites and attach them to a GameObject?

Tags: unity, sprites

I have the following sprites:

Background

[image]

Foreground

[image]

Combined they should look like this:

[image]

The first problem is Unity can only show one sprite with its Sprite Renderer, so I can't combine them with it.

The second problem is the bomb sprite should not be rotating along with the background, like so:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: The simplest answer is to use two GameObjects - one for the background and one for the foreground, each with their own SpriteRenderer. Have you tried this already?

Comment: @DMGregory That's a good idea, but since my game spawns a lot of GameObjects (cubes) constantly, I don't know if adding even more will throttle performance. Considering I'm making this game for mobile.

Comment: Unity is made for handling lots of GameObjects - so when it comes to questions of adding 1 game object or doing something substantially more complicated (like adding a multitexturing material for each icon like this, piling up your draw calls) it's often better to just add the extra object. You can always profile your game to see if the extra gameobjects are adding a substantial burden, but without profiling you might just be making extra work for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have them as different objects and make one of them as main object with the others as children of it. So you can code a behavior for each of them.